# Not allow scroll on window Resize

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to block scrolling on window resize? I have a website which is compose by 4 sections(divs), each one takes the size of the window.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="home" class="section"></div>
<div id="works" class="section"></div>
<div id="contact" class="section"></div>
<div id="about" class="section"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.section{
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".section").height($(window).height());
    $(".section").css("min-height", "768px");
    $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".section").height($(window).height());
    var bodyheight = $(window).height();
    });
  });
```

As you can see I'm adding a code above in which you will see each div have the size of the window and follows the behavior of resizing and have 768px as min-height, but every time I resize it, it jumps (scrolls) to the next section, it's possible to make it stay at the current section when window is resized?

Comment: it works normally with me (when i resize, it stays at where i am before doing it, not sure about your problem, have you tried on different browser? does your code affect it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in Aurora, Opera  and Chrome and it does not scroll to previous content when resized unless there is dynamic content added to the page while the page is resizing.
For instance, I added

```
$('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).width() + '</div>');
```

to your function and then, due to the additional content, there was scrolling on the page

Comment: Yup I forgot to mention that this only happens when im in Firefox, you can check my site and test it with firefox, try resizing it and you will see what I mean [IamFer](http://iamfer.com)